# Are commands phrased in plural the NT to be taken as commands to inviduals?

Tags: translation-philosophy

Grammatically, many commands in the New Testament are plural.  However, they can only be obeyed by individuals.  Does koine Greek syntax allow a singular translation?  References, please.

Comment: Can you provide a few examples of verses in question?  I think this question might be too broad as written.

Answer (score 1):

The Ten Commandments in Exodus and Deuteronomy are singular and scholars says the singular applies to the nation of Israel as a whole, particularly the promise (Exodus 20:12).  This does not mean individuals weren't responsible for keeping the Ten Commandments.  Thus, when speaking to a group, one would expect commands applying to individuals to be plural.